# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PipelineVariable'

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

On two different machines joined to the same Windows 2008 R2 Active Directory domain, a Windows 7 workstation and a Windows 2008 R2 server, I am getting the following error when running a [PowerShell script written by a Microsoft Field Engineer I downloaded from the Microsoft TechNet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Find-missing-Kerberos-SPNs-fbe51894):

> PS C:\Users\User1\Desktop> .\Find-PossibleMissingSPN.ps1
>   
> **Get-ADObject : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PipelineVariable'.**
>   
> At C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Find-PossibleMissingSPN.ps1:37 char:114
>   + Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $filter -SearchBase $DN -SearchScope Subtree -Proper
>   ties $propertylist -PipelineVariable <<<<  account | ForEach-Object {
>       
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADObject], ParameterBi
>      ndingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory
>      .Management.Commands.GetADObject

Various google searches have not yielded an answer.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?  Here's the actual code:

```
#.Synopsis 
# To find possibly missing SPN registrations due to manual mistakes. 
[CmdletBinding()] 
Param 
( 
# start the search at this DN. Default is to search all of the domain. 
   [string]$DN = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName 
) 
# 
# define the SPN service classes to look for. Other types are mostly automated and should be OK.  
# 
$servicesclasses2check = @("host", "cifs", "nfs", "http", "mssql") 
# 
# get computers and users with a nonzero SPN within the given DN. 
# 
$filter = '(&(servicePrincipalname=*)(|(objectcategory=computer)(objectcategory=person)))' 
$propertylist = @("servicePrincipalname", "samaccountname") 
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $filter -SearchBase $DN -SearchScope Subtree -Properties $propertylist -PipelineVariable account | ForEach-Object { 
# 
# Create list of interesting SPNs for each account. Strong assumption for all code: SPN is syntactically correct.  
# 
$spnlist = $account.servicePrincipalName | Where-Object { 
    ($serviceclass, $hostname, $service) = $_ -split '/' 
    ($servicesclasses2check -contains $serviceclass) -and -not $service 
} 
# 
# Look for cases where there is no pair of (host, host.domain) SPNs. 
# 
foreach ($spn in $spnlist) 
{ 
    ($serviceclass, $hostname, $service) = $spn -split '/' 
    if ($service) { $service = "/$service" } 
    ($fullname, $port) = $hostname -split ':' 
    if ($port) { $port = ":$port" } 
    ($shortname, $domain) = $fullname -split '[.]' 
    # 
    # define the regexp matching the missing SPN and go look for it  
    # 
    if ($domain) { 
        $needsSPN =  "${serviceclass}/${shortname}${port}${service}`$" 
        $needsSPNtxt = "${serviceclass}/${shortname}${port}${service}" 
    } else { 
        $needsSPN = "$serviceclass/${shortname}[.][a-zA-Z0-9-]+.*${port}${service}`$" 
        $needsSPNtxt = "$serviceclass/${shortname}.<domain>${port}${service}" 
    } 
    # 
    # search the array of SPNs to see if the _other_ SPN is there. If not, we have problem case.  
    # 
    if (-not ($spnlist -match $needsSPN)) 
    { 
        [PSCustomobject] @{ 
            samaccountname = $account.samaccountname 
            presentSPN = $spn 
            missingSPN = $needsSPNtxt 
        } 
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: The -PipelineVariable common parameter is only available in PowerShell v4+ I believe. What version of PowerShell are you running?

Comment: You tagged the question as V2 so i am assuming you are running on V2. In this case you need to upgrade your PowerShell version or modify the script slightly.

Comment: @OwainEsau - That was it.  My PowerShell V2 was too old and needed to be upgraded to V4 and then it worked.  You can write answer here and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -PipelineVariable common parameter is only available in PowerShell v4+. You need to upgrade to a later version for this to work.